# Prevent scp from copying local files?

Tags: linux, mac, unix, scp

I just read the [Linux scp command issue](https://superuser.com/questions/141977/linux-scp-command-issue) question and it reminded me that I regularily forget to specify the colon in the host part of a scp command, and thus copying a file locally instead of copying to a remote host, e.g. I do

```
scp foo host
```

instead of

```
scp foo host:
```

But I never use scp to copy a file locally. So I wonder if there is a way to make scp fail if both (the source and destination) arguments refer to local files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a wrapper function in Bash and name it `scp` that uses `getopts` to process the options into a new array leaving the source and destination in the positional parameters, then check those for the presence of "@" and ":" and, if absent, issue an error message. If they're present, then call the real `scp` using something like `command scp "${args[@]}" "$source" "$dest"`. The `command` command causes Bash to call the program that's found in the `PATH` instead of the function by the same name.

Since, at least on my system, `scp` only supports the short option type, `getopts` (which also only supports short options) will work fine for this.

The function would look something like this (untested):

```
scp () {
    # wrapper function to prevent scp of local-only files
    options=":346BCpqrTvc:F:i:J:l:o:P:S:"
    while getopts $options option
    do
        case $option in
            3 | 4 | 6 | B | C | p | q | r | T | v)
                args+=($option)
                ;;
            c | F | i | J | l | o | P | S)
                args+=($option "$OPTARG")
                ;;
            \? ) echo "Unknown option: -$OPTARG" >&2; return 1;;
            :  ) echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG" >&2; return 1;;
            *  ) echo "Unimplemented option: -$option" >&2; return 1;;
        esac
    done

    shift $((OPTIND - 1))

    if [[ $1 != *@*:* && $2 != *@*:* ]]
    then
        echo "Local-only copy not permitted"
        echo "to override, use 'command scp ARGS'"
        return 1
    fi
    command scp "${args[@]}" "$1" "$2"
}
```

The options in this script reflect those accepted by `scp` at the time of this writing, but they may change over time. That is one of the risks presented by wrapper scripts such as this.

Comment: Nice trick. However, you should consider naming your wrapper something else than "scp" (maybe "scop"). Overloading well-known commands can be a source of tricky problems because most people/scripts will expect the standard functionality.

Comment: Scripts won't use the overloaded function unless you export the function, for example `scp () { ... }; export scp`

Comment: Oh, @sleske, in addition to the export information in my previous comment, this type of thing is the purpose of the `command` and `builtin` commands rather than being just a nice trick.

Comment: Interesting info about "command" and "builtin", didn't know that. Still, I'd be wary of overloading scp, if just for the "principle of least surprise". Well, maybe a matter of taste...

Comment: There's a missing closing double quote at the end of the `options=` line. I would normally submit an edit but the stupid software requires at least 6 characters to change...

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Thanks! I fixed it. It stood for over 12 years!

Comment: @DennisWilliamson And scp these days has different arguments... so maybe I should submit an edit anyway...

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Thanks. I'll update it and add a note that options change over time.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Why remove the exits?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Not remove; replace with `return`. As I wrote in the edit comment, `exit` will cause the current shell to exit; you need to use `return` inside functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4419956/391445

Answer (score 1):

My `scp` uses the regular `cp` to copy local files.

Create a script named `cp` and make sure `scp` runs with a modified `PATH`, so it finds the script instead of the real `cp`.

The script may be like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Local copying unsupported!' >&2
exit 1
```

Save it as `~/.weird-stuff/cp` and make it executable. Then create a wrapper named `scp` that modifies `PATH` for the real `scp`. Example wrapper function:

```
scp () {
PATH="$HOME/.weird-stuff:$PATH" command scp "$@";
}
```

You may prefer an equivalent wrapper script.

Disadvantage:

- There is no guarantee that future versions of `scp` will rely on `cp`. If `scp` stops relying on `cp` (or on `PATH` to find `cp`) then the solution will stop working.

Advantage:

- The solution (unlike [this one](https://superuser.com/a/141999/432690)) does not need to understand options supported by `scp`. No matter how `scp` interprets its command line or if anything in this matter changes in the future, the solution will work, if only `scp` keeps using `cp` for local copying (and `PATH` to find `cp`).

Answer (score 1):

Low cost solution: **if** you are copying always/often from the same directory, and always/often to the same host, just create a fake file with the name of the host and remove all write permissions on it: `touch host && chmod ugo-w host`. Then your wrong scp command will fail.